How can i make this boostrap5.3 dropdown menu central and that occupied all the width of the page?
I need to make the dropdown menu as this page without the content, that occupies all the width of the page. I also need to make all the "lorem" links of the menu central in the navbar. I'm not able to edit bootstrap classes so I can't make this. How can I fix that? (please open it in full page, and i don't know why with the code snipped the hover menu doesn't work)


.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: darkgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu li:first-child a {
  color: darkgrey;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">

            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>






.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: darkgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-menu li:first-child a {
  color: darkgrey;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">

            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



Add JS Script's and you are missing them?
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


i already did in my full project but it stil doesn't work

Did you add the srcipt tags for the js code?
To use bootstap, you need both popperjs and the bootstrap js code.
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/#cdn-via-jsdelivr

yes i already did
